# Cannot GET / with gridsome develop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, gridsome

I have a problem with a Gridsome project. When I try to access http://localhost:8082/ after running gridsome develop I get the response Cannot GET /. I've got a number of other Gridsome projects that all work fine, it's just one. Gridsome build works fine. Has anyone else had the same issue? My environment is

Node: 18.4.0
npm: 9.1.1
gridsome 0.7.0

Thanks

Expected to see the home page.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browsers dev tool console or network info? Please include details in the question as text rather than as images if possible?

Comment: Yeah the error in the console is 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' and has localhost/:1 which just displays the html for the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.